# CURL PHP Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse an html output that i get through CURL using simple html dom, but I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'innertext' of non-object

This is the relevant code:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === FALSE) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$html = str_get_html($output);
$kungtext_class = $html->find('div[class=kungtext]');
$kungtext = $kungtext_class->innertext;

echo $kungtext;
```

Output variable is the gathered HTML in text-form that I get from CURL.

Comment: can you check what is inside $html ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Yes, it returns the html of the page

Comment: after $html = str_get_html($output); add $html->save(); and check if it works

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Error remains :/

Comment: add this var_dump(get_class($html)); and tell me the result please

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Where do you want me to add this?

Comment: after $html = str_get_html($output); the point is to know the class name of the $html variable

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI string(15) "simple_html_dom"

Comment: can you check what is inside $kungtext_class please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

`$kungtext_class` is giving you an `array`, you can't access the property because you get a bunch of elements, not only one.

See the docs http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

```
mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] )
```

> Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an **array** of object.

So your code should be like

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=kungtext]') as $kungtext_class) {
    echo $kungtext_class->innertext;
}
```

Or, access index `0` (first element):

```
$kungtext_class = $html->find('div[class=kungtext]', 0);
$kungtext = $kungtext_class->innertext;
```

---

**Old answer**

`curl_exec()` by default returns a `boolean`.

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in the curlopts, it then returns the expected string (on success).

```
// Before the curl_exec():
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

> Returns `true` on success or `false` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, `false` on failure.

Comment: I have: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

```
mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] )
```

> Find children by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if
>   index is set, otherwise, return an array of object.

so in your case , the returned value is saved in $kungtext_class, the error you have here can be :

1 - the find call return an array , so you have to do that :

```
foreach($kungtext_class as $element){
     echo $element->innertext;
}
```

2- the find call don't find any element that have the class **kungtext** so it return null and it's normal that the innertext throw error .

Your code will work correctly onyl if the find method return only one element from the dom that have the class **kungtext** .